# why my flutter validator doesn't validate properly?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, validation

I am currently learning Flutter-Validation, I copy and wrote this code from a video, but it automatically passes the validation even if the the condition is false. there are two validation on Username and password, even if I don't write a single character, the validation gets True and passes to next page. The Validation function is written at the start "moveToHome", and it is called from "Material-InkWell" below.

How it should have work:
if the form is empty, it should return error message "Cannot be empty....",

```
import 'package:fir_project/utils/routes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String name = "";
  bool changeButton = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  moveToHome(BuildContext context) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        changeButton = true;
      });
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, Myroutes.homeRoute);
      setState(() {
        changeButton = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/loginimg.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Welcome $name",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 32.0),
                  child: Form(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Enter Username",
                              labelText: "Username"),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return "Username Cannot be Empty";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            name = value;
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Enter Password",
                              labelText: "Password"),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return "Password Cannot be Empty";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 40.0,
                        ),
                        Material(
                          color: Colors.teal,
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(changeButton ? 40 : 8),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              moveToHome(context);
                            },
                            child: AnimatedContainer(
                              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                              height: 50,
                              width: changeButton ? 50 : 150,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: changeButton
                                  ? Icon(
                                      Icons.done,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )
                                  : Text(
                                      "Login",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Here why you have added two form widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using multiple-form widgets

```
return Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(     <-- Form 1
            key: _formKey,
```

and

```
Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 32.0),
                  child: Form(     <-- Form 2
                    child: Column(
```

Remove the second `Form` widget and it should work just fine.

Updated Code:

```html
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String name = "";
  bool changeButton = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  moveToHome(BuildContext context) async {
    print(_formKey.currentState!.validate());
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        changeButton = true;
      });
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, Myroutes.homeRoute);
      setState(() {
        changeButton = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/loginimg.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Welcome $name",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 32.0),
                  child: Container(  <-- Extra Form Widget (Form 2). Replaced the Form With Container
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Enter Username",
                              labelText: "Username"),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return "Username Cannot be Empty";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            name = value;
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Enter Password",
                              labelText: "Password"),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return "Password Cannot be Empty";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 40.0,
                        ),
                        Material(
                          color: Colors.teal,
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(changeButton ? 40 : 8),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              moveToHome(context);
                            },
                            child: AnimatedContainer(
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              height: 50,
                              width: changeButton ? 50 : 150,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: changeButton
                                  ? Icon(
                                      Icons.done,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )
                                  : Text(
                                      "Login",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```